Does regular exponential family have an MLR only when $w(\theta)$ is a non-decreasing function?
Just under Definition 8.3.16 of Statistical Inference by Casella & Berger, it is claimed that any regular exponential family with $ g(t|\theta) = h(t)c(\theta)e^{w(\theta)t} $ has an MLR if $w(\theta)$ is a non-decreasing function. But what happens when $w(\theta)$ is non-increasing? For $\theta_2 > \theta_1$, $\frac{g(t|\theta_2)}{g(t|\theta_1)} = \frac{c(\theta_2)}{c(\theta_1)}e^{(w(\theta_2)-w(\theta_1))t}$ and then since $w(\theta_2) - w(\theta_1) \leq 0$,this function seems to be non-increasing and therefore monotonic. So why do they exclude this case? Is it not necessarily monotonic?

It doesn't need to be. As long as $w(\theta)$ is strictly monotone, there is a UMP.
